# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, turnjs

I've scanned through the site and looked at many replies to people having similar issues but none of the responses have solved my issue!

I'm getting this error only in IE9, and it causes the page to take ages to load. All other browsers and versions of IE seems to be fine! This is the only error that pops up during debugging..

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'turn' 
www.wilnecotehighprospectus.co.uk, line 853 character 2
```

I don't suppose anyone has any ideas? I've been literally pulling my hair out on this for weeks.

URL: http://www.wilnecotehighprospectus.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: unable to reproduce your issue on IE9 mode under IE10

Comment: I'm not either. I'm having to use teamviewer to access a machine at the school to replicate the issue! Seems to be an issue for a lot of schools - I thought at first it may be an issue with some sort of network configuration but the techies there have assured it me it does the same on their laptops at home.